# Talz Apartment now "Impostor"?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Okay, so I built a residential apartment which was supposed to be the Talz apartment building. But all that shows after construction is a starry background with "Impostor" graffitied across in red. What the hell is going on?

Note: I have still been able to move residents into the building.

Answer (score 1):

Other people had a similar problem. Some new bitizens had "Impostor" as their dream job. Actually they had new, not added then levels like Bongo Sandwiches as their dream jobs. After fully restarting the app it . But I haven't heard about levels having a different background...
Try to completely close your app and start it again anyway (however, I'm not sure if it works on Android)

Comment: I've tried exiting the app, even restarted my iphone and it simply won't go away!

Comment: @Symdawg93 Don't just exit the app. Double tap the home button and force close it.

Comment: @Nzall I think restarting the phone would restart all the apps, no?

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein Depends on the brand of phone. Depending on the manufacturer, some phones may suspend some apps to memory rather than completely shut them down.